# Why does my image url from Amazon S3 have AWSaccesskey and expiration even though I made the bucket public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Here is the policy I added:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "MakeItPublic",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created an IAM and attached the AmazonS3FullAccess to that IAM.

In my rails app, I display the pictures like this:

```
- @pictures.each do |picture|
  %img{src: picture.image_url}
```

and the generated url is something like:

```
https://leaguedraw.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/73dfe6c6-0c25-496c-be9f-6f2beb75d7c3.png?AWSAccessKeyId=myaccesskey&Expires=1434472944&Signature=d1vIYOQt410%2BgcXs6%2BATSCsG2Mk%3D
```

when I just want this:

```
https://leaguedraw.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/73dfe6c6-0c25-496c-be9f-6f2beb75d7c3.png
```

What else do I need to do to generate the latter url?

Additional info: using carrierwave gem and carrierwave-aws gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to change the acl in the configuration file from

```
config.aws_acl = :'public-read'
```

to

```
config.aws_acl = :public_read
```

even though the documentation said to use `:'public-read'`.